# put command placing file in hdfs but not able to display the same

Tags: hadoop

below mentioned is output when i am placing file in the HDFS using put command.

```
[root@PPWFMD509 bin]# ./hadoop fs -put /data/test.txt /dir1/test.txt
14/02/25 12:58:40 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
put: file /dir1/test.txt._COPYING_ on client 127.0.0.1.
```

when i want to retrieve the same hdfs message is "File Not found" shown below.

```
[root@PPWFMD509 bin]# ./hadoop fs -cat /dir1/test.txt
14/02/25 13:00:37 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
cat: `/dir1/test.txt': No such file or directory
```

Event -lsr command is displaying the directory but not the file. shown below.

```
[root@PPWFMD509 bin]# ./hadoop fs -lsr /
lsr: DEPRECATED: Please use 'ls -R' instead.
14/02/25 13:01:25 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
drwxr-xr-x   - root supergroup          0 2014-02-24 17:25 /dir1
drwxr-xr-x   - root supergroup          0 2014-02-25 11:52 /dir2
```

Pls. let me know if someone has fixed the same issue.

Comment: Can you check what `echo $?` is after you execute `put` command.

Comment: [root@PPWFMD509 bin]# echo $?
1

Comment: According to this [link](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r0.18.3/hdfs_shell.html#put) the exit code should be `0` if command is successful. Since you get a non-zero value I assume your put command is not working correctly. Check the logs if you can find additional error messages. Check if the user writing to HDFS (user running the command) has permissions to write to HDFS

Comment: Thank You very much. It was dfs.replication parameter set incorrectly. Had the clue from the namenode.log file.